# How to submit a function and continue with the next steps without waiting for this function to be finished?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracleforms

I have a code like this:

```
FOR i IN 1 .. 20 
LOOP
   F(i); -- for each i, F(i) takes 20 minutes to be executed
END LOOP;
```

I am looking for a way to call F(2) exactly after calling F(1). I mean I do not want to wait for F(1) to be executed successfully and then call F(2).

My aim is that the whole loop takes 20 minutes instead of 400 minutes. What is the best way to implement this in the Oracle Forms?!

If it is not possible to implement it in the forms, i can create a pl/sql function to do this and then call this pl/sql function form my form.

Does anyone have a amazing idea?!

Thanks!
MAX

Comment: [Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:146612348066) says in PLSQL this can't be done  If this is pure oracle forms: Perhaps https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/6je9h0329/index.html may help.

Comment: F is a pure PL/SQL function. Not linked to a job.

Comment: Cannot we tell oracle to just call F, and continue?! Assume that I don't care about the result.

Comment: Cannot I run them parallel!?

Comment: This is tagged for both Oracle and SQL Server.  Are you really looking for a solution that works for both?  Or should the SQL Server tag be removed because you're really just looking at Oracle.  Is `f` a stored procedure in the database?  Or a PL/SQL function that just runs in the Oracle Forms PL/SQL JVM?

Comment: SQL tags were removed. I thiught it worked in the same way. F is a prgram unit on Oracle Forms. It will be great if I find a way to implement in the forms, it will save me some hours. But if we don't have a solution on forms, and just we have a way that works on  pl/SQL store procedures, I can write a store procedure in database and then just call it from the forms. Do you have a solution?

Comment: I did as you said, but it did not work. I keep the start time of F(1) to F(20). They are not called in parallel. They are called in order.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at submitting an immediate run once dbms_job which will run asynchronously via the DBMS job scheduler. As you say you are not concerned with the result which would be a big issue with this approach if you were. Here is an example plsql block which you would change to just the single dbms_job line call in your loop:

```
SQL> set serverout on
SQL> DECLARE
  2    jno BINARY_INTEGER;
  3  BEGIN
  4    dbms_job.submit(JOB       => jno,
  5                    WHAT      => 'declare X varchar2(200); BEGIN X := F(2) END;',
  6                    NEXT_DATE => SYSDATE);
  7    dbms_output.put_line(jno);
  8    COMMIT;  
  9  END;
 10  /
```

A good reference is here:

http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_job.html

Keep in mind that most DBAs will set a limit to the amount of concurrent dbms_jobs that can be run concurrently.

Comment: I tried but something is fishy. Look at my new post on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808397/why-dbms-job-submit-doesnt-work-while-the-same-code-work-with-execute-immediate?noredirect=1#comment57362265_34808397

Comment: Make sure you put  a "commit" in your code. Make sure that the dbms_job scheduler is running - "select * from all_jobs" in your session. If all works please accept the answer and mark up.

Answer (score -1):

Asynchronous jobs can be run from Oracle forms using a java bean. [This article](http://forms.pjc.bean.over-blog.com/article-3664823.html) has the details.