# why dbms_job.submit doesn't work while the same code work with execute immediate?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracleforms

This is the frist time that I am going to use dbms_job.submit.

The following piece of code doesn't work:

```
    declare
    i_job_no BINARY_INTEGER;
begin
    dbms_job.submit(JOB => i_job_no, what =>  'declare x number; begin x := f_threads(''my_program'', '|| 6058883 ||' , '|| 2 || '); end;', next_date => sysdate);

    dbms_output.put_line(i_job_no);
end;
```

but the same thing works fine with execute immediate. Can anyone help?!

```
> declare
    i_job_no BINARY_INTEGER;
begin
    execute immediate  'declare x number; begin x := f_threads(''my_program'', '|| 6058883 ||' , '|| 2 || '); end;';
end;
```

thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "does'nt work"? Maybe you don't have required database processes started

Comment: I dont get any error message

Answer (score 1):

in this way your pl/sql block will work:

```
      declare
        i_job_no BINARY_INTEGER;
    begin
        dbms_job.submit(JOB => i_job_no, what =>  'declare x number; begin x := f_threads(''my_program'', '|| 6058883 ||' , '|| 2 || '); end;', next_date => sysdate);

        dbms_output.put_line(i_job_no);
        commit;
    end;
```

You are missing a `commit` in you code

Regards
Giova

Comment: I aded the commit but it still foesn't work. It does not call the f_threads at all. I put a dbms_output.put_line('I am here') at the top of the function.

Comment: Pls try to add schema name as prefix of the function

Comment: I added the schema name before the function name, it didn't solve my problem. I googled a little bit.   This dbms_job.submit just submit the jjob in user_jobs. When I run the above code, I write 20 jobs into user_jobs table. The question is still how to run them in parallel?

Comment: we can use dbms_job.run to run the submitted jobs, but it wont be in parallel.

Comment: The number of jobs running in parallrl is determinated by Orscle instance oarameter job_queue_processes. You ar troubleshooting a problem. Pls simplify it. For the first try  to run a single job. Then execute 20 jobs.....

Comment: a single job is run fine when I submit the job (dbms_job.submit) and then run the job dbms_job.run(i_job_no)

Comment: but when I try to run all 20 jobs it takes long time because they are executed in sequence.

Comment: you have to increment your job_queue_processes parameter  value. Googke on it. Alter system set job_queue_processes=25 for example

Comment: if I alter it to 25, will always 25 jobs be able to be run in parallel? this is no good. I just want some solution for my specific problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100908/discussion-between-dax-and-giova).

Comment: On oracle jobs are workibg in this way. They depends on job_queue_processes.  You have to finde a different approach. I can't chat. I'm keeping an airplane in minutes. Let me know in the next days.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
declare
  i_job_no BINARY_INTEGER;
begin
  dbms_job.submit(JOB => i_job_no, what =>  'declare x number; begin x := f_threads(''my_program'', '|| 6058883 ||' , '|| 2 || '); end;', next_date => sysdate);
  dbms_output.put_line(i_job_no);
  commit;
  dbms_job.run(i_job_no);
end;
```